# Where default PATH environment variable is defined

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I've written a simple experiment which consists of cpp and shell. The main thing that cpp does is `execve("./test.sh", NULL, NULL);`, and shell tries to output environment variables as follows:

```
printenv
echo "PATH: $PATH"
```

It's quite expected that the environment is empty since I've sent no environment variables, but I get the following output:

```
PWD=/home/user/code/security_playground/display_path
PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

So, first of all, the environment is not empty. Thus, the first question is how the environment is populated? What are defaults and minimal environment you could possibly get and where is it defined (if defined in config, etc.)?

Second question is where did PATH emerge from. It's not printed by `printenv`, but it's there if I print it with echo, and test.sh is still capable of calling utilities. Brief googling gave me an idea of `/etc/environment`, but it's contents is different:

```
└─$ cat /etc/environment                                                                                                                                                                   
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Which, by the way, is surprisingly empty. Why?

I do realize that much of that should be somewhere in docs, but all my googling lead me to quite generic environment descriptions, so any answers or search hints are welcome.

Comment: There isn't a standardized answer to the question "where is the default value of PATH set".  It depends on the platform — AFAIK, even differing between different Linux distros.

Comment: Check ~/.profile and /etc/profile

Comment: When you use `execve()` with `NULL` as the third argument, you are giving the executed program an empty environment.  There will be no values in the environment.  If that's not what you intend to do, don't use `execve()` like that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think that is what he intends, which is why he's surprised that the `PATH` variable is printed.

Comment: This is not really a programming question but rather a shell and Linux system question. For example: [Complete view of where the PATH variable is set in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash).

Comment: A shell _might_ [will probably] set a default value for `PATH` if there isn't one. You could look at (e.g.) `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`. These may `source` a file like `/etc/profile.d/whatever`. If your _target_ program was _another_ C program you created, the program would probably behave as you expect. You could use: `#!/bin/bash -` as the first line to _suppress_ reading of `~/.bashrc` et. al.

Comment: Do: `cd /etc; grep PATH= -r .`.

Comment: ...though what files are in `/etc` doesn't really answer the question -- noninteractive shells aren't obligated by POSIX to read anything from `/etc` at all. If the environment variable `ENV` contains a filename, that file will be sourced, but there's no `ENV` here at all.

Comment: That said, this isn't an answerable question right now -- there's not just one shell in existence, and whereas the POSIX standard specifies _some_ behavior, it doesn't specify _all_ behavior. To provide an answer for this, I'd really need a complete reproducer in the form of something like a Docker image (thus containing a _specific_ shell and runtime environment); and there's no guarantee that that answer would be portable to any other environment.

Comment: (mind, `PWD` itself is specified by POSIX, and the standard instructs the shell to initialize it during startup, so that one's no surprise at all).

Comment: ...also, per POSIX, behavior when `PATH` is not set at shell initialization time are implementation-defined.

Comment: What shell does that script run under? The way it's shown, there's no hashbang line, and at least on my Linux, `execve()` on such a file just returns an error. I think `printenv` is from csh, but seems to exist as an external utility too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where default PATH environment variable is defined

It *depends*. On the distribution, on the shell, on the environment, on OS, on configuration files.

I have some systems at hand, I see:

- ArchLinux [adds to PATH in /etc/profile](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/filesystem/trunk/profile#L18).
- OpenSuSE [has yet a different code that adds to PATH from /etc/profile](https://github.com/openSUSE/aaa_base/blob/master/files/etc/profile#L167)
- CentOS7 has [has yet a different code in /etc/profile](https://gist.github.com/mdeguzis/963a6f8b387ba0c4c23e7dd14e7aa826#file-profile-L37)

I suspect that each distribution places files in slightly different places, they will ship with slightly different configuration.

> how the environment is populated?

Bash has [DEFAULT_PATH_VALUE](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/config-top.h#L65) that [is used when PATH is not set](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/variables.c#L495). But don't look at the default value too much - [package distrbutors overwrite it](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/bash/trunk/PKGBUILD#L46).

There is `/etc/environment` (and `pam_env.conf`) that are read by PAM on login. So when you login. But not when you `chroot`.

The is `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` files read by the shell. These scripts may read other files. So usually there is drop-in dir `/etc/profile.d/*`.

In bash there is `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` `/etc/bash.login` `/etc/bash.logout` or similar and user configuration files ``~/.bashrc`etc. In bash also`/etc/bash_completion.d`and all scripts in`/usr/share/bash_completion`are also sourced, when completion is enabled. BUT these files are for Bourne shell - there are also other shells, notably`zsh`and`csh`, and people use them and they have different syntax and different set of startup files.

**Each** of these scripts can manipulate `PATH`, it can reset it, append to it, do whatever it wants to it.

And there are also different set of files read on login/non-login + interactive/non-interactive shells, and these files can include each other (it's common to have `.bash_profile` or other files that just `source .bashrc` or similar).

> What are defaults

The `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` looks like a good default that should be safe on any linux.

> by the way, is surprisingly empty. Why?

My `/etc/environment` file [is just empty](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_env/environment) and has only the default comment in `linux-pam` package. `/etc/environment` has a very simple syntax and is read by `pam` (there may be no pam on your system...). To modify *shell* environment, one would prefer *shell* files - so `/etc/profile` is the place to keep system modifications. Also `/etc/environment` has simple key=value syntax, wherea's in `/etc/profile` you have, well, shell. And `/etc/environment` is read *on login* by PAM - so putting `PATH` just there would break I think for example `docker`, it just runs a shell in chroot, there is login.

Comment: The OP is asking how PATH is set _after a noninteractive shell is directly invoked by a C executable with no environment variables set_. Much of this answer isn't scoped to that specific case; `.bashrc` isn't run by noninteractive interpreters; neither are `.login`/`.logout`, or `/etc/profile`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To quote [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> If PATH is unset or is set to null, the path search is implementation-defined.

One way way an implementation can behave when PATH is initially unset is to simply set it to a hardcoded value. (It could also refuse to run any external executables at all, or throw monkeys at your face; "implementation defined" means the standard takes no position on what the computer does in the circumstance at hand, so it's unwise to make *any* assumption about what that behavior will be).

---

Similarly, for `PWD`, with emphasis added:

> The value is set by the `cd` utility, **and by the `sh` utility during initialization**

...so initializing this at shell startup time is explicitly mandated by the standard.